# On the correspondent relationship between modules and forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory

Given a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M = \langle 1, \omega_1, \dots, \omega_m \rangle$ contained in the algebraic number field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_m)$, there is an irreducible form $F(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_m)$ of degree $n$ defined as $F(x_0,x_1, \dots, x_m) = N(x_0 + x_1\omega_1+\dots+x_m\omega_m)$ associated with it, where $N$ denotes the norm $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$, $x_0, \dots, x_m$ taking values from $\mathbb{Z}$.

I wonder whether $M$ is unique with respect to the form $F$ in the following sense: suppose $N = \langle \xi_0, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_m \rangle$ is another $\mathbb{Z}$-module in an algebraic number field $K' = \mathbb{Q}(\xi_0, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_m)$, such that $F = N_{K'/\mathbb{Q}}(x_0\xi_0+x_1\xi_1+\dots+x_m\xi_m)$, then $\{\xi_0, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_m\} = \{1\sigma, \omega_1\sigma, \dots, \omega_m\sigma\}$ for some $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(\bar{K}/\mathbb{Q})$, where $\bar{K}$ denotes the normal closure of $K$.

**My attempts**: I can only prove that the two sets above differ by a multiple of some algebraic number $\alpha$, or equivalently $M\sigma = \alpha N$, by unique factorization of polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}$. I cannot further prove or disprove it.

**The origin of the problem**: The problem occurs to me when reading Borevich & Shafarevich's *Number Theory*, where the author states that different sets of generators of the same module $M$ give rise to equivalent forms.

Comment: You should be able to show that $N(\alpha) = 1$ and then I think that's the best you can say. Also you need $K$ to be Galois.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan There is an error in my description. It should be $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{K}/\mathbb{Q})$ instead of $\operatorname{Gal}({K}/\mathbb{Q})$, where $\bar{K}$ denotes the normal closure of $K$. Then we do not need $K$ to be Galois.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Also, I cannot see how one is able to deduce $N(\alpha) = 1$, since the norm in the first paragraph might be different from that in the second paragraph (they are, respectively, $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ and $N_{K'/\mathbb{Q}}$)?

Comment: The condition that $N(\alpha) = 1$ doesn't depend on this choice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Would you please provide more details? I am still confused how to show $N(\alpha) = 1$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this chapter II, section 1, paragraph 2, theorem 2 in Borevich—Shafarevich? In 3rd Russian edition (1985) it says *"...Conversely, every irreducible decomposable form is **up to a constant factor** equivalent to a form as in (4)"*, where (4) is $F(x_1, \ldots, x_m) = N(x_1+x_2\mu_2+\ldots+x_m\mu_m)$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I don't think so. Theorem 2 asserts that every irreducible decomposable form can be given by taking norm in some module, while what I ask is whether every irreducible decomposable form is given by a **unique** module in certain sense.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Would you please show how to deduce $N(\alpha) = 1$? I still cannot figure it out.